# Programatically execute command to close current buffer and switch to last state

Tags: vim

I'm editing a file `:e foo`.

Now I'd like to save it, close the buffer (so I can go back to the state before I opened `foo`), using a `command`.

I have this right now:

```
command! GC silent execute ":wq" | silent execute ":close"
```

But if I didn't have any buffer open before, I get this error:

```
E444: Cannot close last window
```

How can I close the window, such that if it's the last window, it still closes it, and returns me back to the empty screen that you get when you just run `vim`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `:update` + `:bdelete` command combination. The first persists changes if there are any, and the latter removes the buffer. If there are other split windows, the current one is closed. Otherwise, if you have other arguments / hidden buffers, the next one is displayed in the single window. If there is no other window, an empty buffer (like `:enew`) is shown.

Answer (score 0):

What you see when you start Vim without a file as argument, `$ vim`, is just an empty buffer. If its state is not altered in any way it is discarded when you do `:e file`.

You can see that with `:ls`: the only buffer available is `file`.

If you want an empty buffer (and I have no idea why you would want that) you'll need to create one explicitly with:

```
:enew
```

unless there's an option that I don't know about.

Anyway, I'd suggest you to do:

```
$ vim file
```

rather than:

```
$ vim
:e file
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do `save all files, and exit vim` ? Then just type `ZZ`.
Or you want to do `save all files if updated, and close all windows` ? Then

```
command! GC bufdo update | windo bw
```